# Test SSL on Android

Tags: android, ssl

I write application which will communicate with HTTP server using SSL. I'm using information from [site](http://blog.antoine.li/2010/10/22/android-trusting-ssl-certificates/) to send data from Android. I know that to test Android code I need to generate certificates, then configure Apache and write server which will receive data from Android but my problem is that I dont know to much about WEB developing and I cant write anything to test. Do u know any quick and easy way to test my Android code?

Comment: That is an interesting (and disturbing) fact in the link... +1

Comment: Use Charles Proxy to test if SSL handshake is happening properly or not. Just google around with Charles Proxy Android and you will find blogs and links based on the same. If the SSL handshake is not proper you will be able to see the data clearly passing through network.